# gsettings commmands and their gconftool-2 alternatives

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I installed a package `gsettings-desktop-schemas` that installs databases/schemas used by a lot of new GTK apps. It also installs a tool `gsettings` that we can use to tweak the schemas in order to affect the look of the applications:

```
gsettings set $gnome-schema gtk-theme 'ziga-gruvbox'
gsettings set $gnome-schema icon-theme 'Papirus-Dark'
gsettings set $gnome-schema cursor-theme 'Adwaita'
gsettings set $gnome-schema font-name 'DejaVu Sans:style=Book'
```

But some applications use older databases / schemas that I install with a package `gconf2`. This gives me a tool `gconftool-2` that can be used to set values in these older databases / schemas.

But how can I use `gconftool-2` to create alternative commands to the above `gsettings` commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gconf` as below:

## Change GTK Theme

For native GNOME 2 with old Debian / Ubuntu / Fedoras

```
gconftool-2 –type=string –set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme "Menta"
```

## Change WINDOW THEME (Metacity)

```
gconftool –type=string –set /desktop/cinnamon/windows/theme "Menta"
```

GNOME 2 (In Gnome 2 with Metacity)

```
gconftool-2 –type=string –set /apps/metacity/general/theme "Menta"
```

## Change GTK COLOR SCHEME

To set color

```
gconftool-2 –type=string –set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_color_scheme
```

To reset color

```
gconftool-2 –type=string –set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_color_scheme ""
```

Comment: I found out that Gimp is not affected by any of your suggestions. It is only affected by setting `/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`. So some applications only use files and don't  use databases...